# Error ionic build android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm facing this issues and none of answers i got from stackoverflow can resolve this. Everything is good for creating apps with start from `npm install -g cordova ionic`, `ionic start myApp tabs` but facing the error when trying to build into android platform by using this command `ionic build android`. Here the output of errors i got from cmd :

**One**

[image]

**Two**

[image]

**Three**

[image]

**Development Environment**

1. Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
2. Ionic Version: 1.2.1
3. Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.12
4. Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
5. OS: Windows 7 SP1
6. Node Version: v4.2.4

All three pictures above are connected respectively. Any of you ever experiencing this issues? Any helps would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

android.webkit.ClientCertRequest is newly added in API level 21.

Install Android build tools version 21 and 22 from SDK Manager.

Once the build tools are installed, remove the platforms and add again and try it.

Check more info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877109/cordova-android-project-doesnt-compile)

Comment: Really? Thought so cause I'm only have level 20 top. Downloading now..... Let you know after trying. Thanks mate.

Comment: Hope it will save your day :)

Comment: Thanks mate. Working perfectly. You saved my day :)