# Running the Cordova Maps Sample project on Netbeans

Tags: android, cordova, netbeans

I have been trying to run the **Cordova** Maps Sample project on **Netbeans**. I was following the instructions given on the [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt4uHSiO-00). When I try to run the project it gives me an error

**The Logcat Error:**

```
Error: CordovaError: The plugin 'cordova-plugin-compat' is required by (cordova-plugin-contacts, cordova-plugin-geolocation), skipping uninstallation.
at runUninstallPlatform (C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\uninstall.js:272:30)
at C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\uninstall.js:96:16
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
at runSingle (C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
at flush (C:\Users\VS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
Result: 1
```

I tried running the following command **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat** ,but, it gives me a message saying **Plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" already installed on android.**

Can somebody advise me as to where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Sachin

Comment: I have used the solution given in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877109/cordova-android-project-doesnt-compile) and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the plugin and adding it again.

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-compat

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-compat
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to remove it but I get an error **Error: The plugin 'cordova-plugin-compat' is required by (cordova-plugin-contact
s, cordova-plugin-geolocation), skipping uninstallation.**

Comment: First remove cordova-plugin-contacts and cordova-plugin-geolocation.

And add again

Comment: Thanks. I tried but could not succeed. It is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

On the Netbeans screen look for "Important Files" folder and inside that should be a "Cordova Plugins" folder.

Right click on the "Cordova Plugins" folder and select "Edit".

Immediately after all the comments (they're lines that start with #) you'll see the list of plugins start. Add a new plugin before all the others that looks like:

```
cordova-plugin-compat=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-compat.git
```

Rebuild the application and it should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @kevin-lynn I tried this and it compiled the application without any problem. Unfortunately, when I load the application on an android, it gives me an error **"[ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found"**. Can you advise me on this problem?. Thanks - Sachin